# What exactly does domain.dispose() do in nodejs? Are there any hooks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

Reading the documentation at http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html makes it a little vague: "*makes a best effort attempt to clean up any and all IO that is associated with the domain*". It mentions that timers are shutdown, which isn't exactly IO. It would be very nice to know the comprehensive list of things domain.dispose does. Does anyone have that list?

Also, is there any way to hook into that functionality - ie allow some custom clean up code to be called when domain.dispose() is run?

Answer (score 5):

The dispose function calls the exit and dispose functions, removes all listeners, removes all error handlers, and attempts to kill all members of the domain. The function the checks if the domain has a parent, and if it does, then it is removed from the domain. The domain is then set for garbage collection, and the marked as disposed.

From the Node documentation:

> Once the domain is disposed the dispose event will emit.

I would go more in-depth on the topic, but the Node source is already nicely annotated.

The timer you are talking about would be here, where the members of the domain are being iterated through.

```
this.members.forEach(function(m) {
  // if it's a timeout or interval, cancel it.
  clearTimeout(m);
});
```

Here's from the Node [source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/domain.js):

```
Domain.prototype.dispose = function() {
  if (this._disposed) return;

  // if we're the active domain, then get out now.
  this.exit();

  this.emit('dispose');

  // remove error handlers.
  this.removeAllListeners();
  this.on('error', function() {});

  // try to kill all the members.
  // XXX There should be more consistent ways
  // to shut down things!
  this.members.forEach(function(m) {
    // if it's a timeout or interval, cancel it.
    clearTimeout(m);

    // drop all event listeners.
    if (m instanceof EventEmitter) {
      m.removeAllListeners();
      // swallow errors
      m.on('error', function() {});
    }

    // Be careful!
    // By definition, we're likely in error-ridden territory here,
    // so it's quite possible that calling some of these methods
    // might cause additional exceptions to be thrown.
    endMethods.forEach(function(method) {
      if (typeof m[method] === 'function') {
        try {
          m[method]();
        } catch (er) {}
      }
    });

  });

  // remove from parent domain, if there is one.
  if (this.domain) this.domain.remove(this);

  // kill the references so that they can be properly gc'ed.
  this.members.length = 0;

  // finally, mark this domain as 'no longer relevant'
  // so that it can't be entered or activated.
  this._disposed = true;
};
```

Comment: So looks like the "dispose" event might be the hook I was wondering about. Seems strange they don't check if the member is a timeout before they use clearTimeout on it. It kinda seems wrong that they hide uncaught exceptions from the endMethods they run. What are the set of things that become "domain members"? Is there a way to make custom objects become a domain member? The source isn't clear about that.

Comment: Yeah, those methods don't seem very clean, although I'm not a very experienced coder so I don't know much better. I do have a question - what type of custom objects are you talking about? A member is any type of `EventEmitter`, since domains are specifically used handle multiple I/O operations as a single group.

Comment: The custom objects i'm talking are really anything you could think of. One example is some module for handling TCP communication on some proprietary protocol. There could be some specific messages expected by the protocol in the case of errors that you would want to send before dying via dispose(). It would be nice to be able to make sure your custom stuff is just as cleanly disposable as core IO functionality and the like.

Comment: Objects as in `EventEmitters`..? I'm not really getting what you're trying to do, are you trying to make it so all instances of something are started in a domain?

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything specific, I'm trying to understand the possibilities.

Comment: Does the `dispose` event not fulfill your purpose then?

Comment: I'm still not sure. Are you saying that if I create an object that inherits from EventEmitter, that object will be disposed of when the domain it's inside is disposed? From the code, it looks to me like the only members that get disposed are ones explicitly added to the domain - this doesn't match with how they described "all IO associated with the domain"

Comment: When adding members to domains, it's added to an object. Then when you invoke `dispose()`, a loop iterates through that object only, and not any deeper. Therefore my answer is no they won't be disposed, and that if you're going to add things to a domain, they should be `EventEmitter`s.

Comment: I thought `Domain.prototype.dispose` was deprecated

Comment: The `Domain.prototype.dispose` method no longer exists tmk: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/domain.js